# How to use a jquery function in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I wrote a little program in angular containing a method which search for a string in a string array like that :

```
function searchStringInArray(str, strArray) {
  for (var j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++) {
    if (strArray[j].match(str)) return j;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

To optimize my code, I thought about using jquery because we can do that in just one line (just by using the minified version in angular) **WITHOUT importing the jquery library** (before the angular script).

So, I wanted to try this new code :

```
$scope.check = $.inArray($scope.message, $scope.messages) ;
```

But it didn't work at all, the console tells me that $ is not defined.

Here is a test code in plunker : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/ftNU3UM7UpKvgL0Jozdy?p=preview

Can you help me to fix that problem?

Thank you

Comment: By default Angular includes jQuery lite and only supports a small set of methods, you'll need to use the full jQuery library if you want `$.inArray` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 1):

You can store the $ of jQuery in any variable for escape the conflict between two languages.

The noConflict() method releases the hold on the $ shortcut identifier, so that other scripts can use it.

For Example:-

```
var jq = $.noConflict(); jq(document).ready(function(){
jq("button").click(function(){
    jq("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
});});
```